# `Enter Activity Number: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

Newbie here, The program works, I can call the class but I don't know what is this. I tried to search but it's not the same problem I encounter

```
import java.util.*;

public class mid_term {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean ok = true;
        Act1 act_1 = new Act1();

        do {
            System.out.println("Midterm Project...Press [0] to exit.\n\n\n");
            System.out.println("[1] Activity 1 (Grade Calculator).");


            System.out.print("Enter Activity Number: ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                act_1.main(args);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        } while (ok);
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Act1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Prelim Grade: ");
        double prelim = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter Midterm Grade: ");
        double midterm = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter Final Grade: ");
        double finals = input.nextDouble();

        
        double result = ((prelim*.30) +(midterm*.30)+ (finals*.40));
        System.out.println("Final Ratings: " + result);

        input.close();

    }
}
```

> Enter Activity Number: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

How can I solve this?

```
Enter Activity Number: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at mid_term.main(mid_term.java:23)
```

Comment: Read [the Javadoc of `Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) (and `Scanner` more generally), that explains what a `NoSuchElementException` indicates: basically, you're trying to read something when the `Scanner` has nothing more to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class Act1 you call

```
 input.close();
```

it closes your System.in stream in the end of the 1st iteration.

In the class mid_term you have an **infinite loop**, if you want your program work **without NoSuchElementException**, you should keep your stream open. Delete the

```
input.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a couple of problems with your code, first of all you should not make another "main" method in your Act1 class. The main method is the first method that is invoked when you run your code, usually you only want to make one of them. There is also no reason to make it static because you created an Act1 object. Static methods are used when you dont need an object to invoke them.

The reason for why it gives you an error is because you are making two different scanners scanning System.in at the same time, I think. To fix this simply pass your scanner from the "mid_term" class to the method in Act1 (which you have hopefully renamed at this point). Also make sure not to close it at the end because otherwise it will just crash once the while loop in mid_term repeats itself.

You also might want to consider renaming "mid_term", in java it is common practise to spell the first letter of your class capitally and use camel case instead of underscores